# responses mock requests.ConnectionError, assert function

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, mocking

I have a function that returns `False` if a `requests.ConnectionError` occurred. 
How can I test the result of the function in case this exception happens?

The following test fails with the Exception rather than asserting that the function should return `False`

```
@responses.activate
def test_get_system_mem_failure(self):
    responses.add(responses.GET,"https://myapi.com/api",
        body=Exception(requests.ConnectionError))
    with pytest.raises(requests.ConnectionError):
        self.assertEqual(sm.get_system_mem(),False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from Github user hramezani 
Assuming that the function is something like this:

```
def test_func():
    try:
        # some code which calls https://myapi.com/api and
        # might cause requests.ConnectionError
        requests.get("https://myapi.com/api")
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False
```

You can test your function behavior(return Fales in case of requests.ConnectionError) like this:

```
@responses.activate
def test_get_system_mem_failure():
    responses.add(responses.GET,"https://myapi.com/api",
        body=requests.ConnectionError())

    assert test_func() is False
```